# How to enable trend diagram?

Tags: hudson

In a newly installed Hudson 3.0.1-b2 server under CentOS 6 Linux we have 3 nodes (created 2 by cloning the first one), but only the 1st one has this nice diagram on the right side:

[image]

Does anybody please know, how to enable it for all nodes?

I don't think I need to install any plugin - because the diagram is already being shown for one of the nodes.

I haven't found the answer in the Hudson wiki yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Diagram should be shown for each Job with configured unit tests.

I don't think that nodes have something to do with this.

It shows up once the job has been run **more** than one time with test results available.

Comment: That's strange - I've created nodes and jobs by cloning. And I do have more that 1 run.

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether we understand each other correctly: Each Job can run on multiple Nodes. So the amount of nodes is not really important for your job trend.